# Which is better approach, to save a value or evaluate each time?

Tags: arrays, swift, optimization, higher-order-functions

I am trying to understand which of the following would be a better approach.

I have an `Array` of `struct`s

```
struct A {
    var selectionCount: Int
}

var ayes = [A]()
```

Should I loop over the items each time if I want to know if any element has been selected.

```
func selectedCount() -> Int {
    return ayes.filter({ $0.selectionCount != 0 }).reduce(0, +)
}
// OR
```

Store a `var` and access it each time if I want to know if any selection has been made.

```
var totalSelectedElements = 0

func select(at: Int) {
    ayes[at].selectionCount += 1
    totalSelectedElements += 1
}

func deselect(at: Int) {
    ayes[at].selectionCount -= 1
    totalSelectedElements -= 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to distinguish *interface* from *implementation*.  First design the interface you want, and then you can always changed the internal implementation to suit your (performance vs. storage) needs.

I believe the array of `A` should be protected and you should only allow access via the `select(at:)` and `deselect(at:)` methods.  This allows you to do the internal implementation either way:

```
struct Ayes {
    private struct A {
        var selectionCount = 0
    }

    private var ayes = [A](repeating: A(), count: 100)
    private var totalSelectedElements = 0

    mutating func select(at: Int) {
        ayes[at].selectionCount += 1
        totalSelectedElements += 1
    }

    mutating func deselect(at: Int) {
        guard ayes[at].selectionCount > 0 else { return }
        ayes[at].selectionCount -= 1
        totalSelectedElements -= 1
    }

    func selectCount(at: Int) -> Int {
        return ayes[at].selectionCount
    }

    var totalElements: Int {
        return totalSelectedElements
    }
}
```

It really depends on how often you will be accessing the `totalElements` whether you want to store it or compute it.  By hiding that implementation detail, you are free to change the implementation without affecting the rest of your program.

I like the idea of maintaining the count for quick access, and by protecting access to the internal implementation you can guarantee that the count is accurate.

---

**Example:**

```
var ayes = Ayes()

print(ayes.totalElements) // 0
ayes.select(at: 3)
ayes.select(at: 3)
ayes.select(at: 4)
print(ayes.totalElements) // 3
print(ayes.selectCount(at: 3)) // 2
ayes.deselect(at: 3)
print(ayes.selectCount(at: 3)) // 1
ayes.deselect(at: 3)
print(ayes.selectCount(at: 3)) // 0
ayes.deselect(at: 3)
print(ayes.selectCount(at: 3)) // 0
print(ayes.totalElements) // 1
```

---

**Alternate Implementation - same interface**

This solution combines [@RakeshaShastri's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202575/1630618) of using a dictionary with your idea of maintaining a count:

```
struct Ayes {
    private var ayes = [Int : Int]()
    private var totalSelectedElements = 0

    mutating func select(at: Int) {
        ayes[at, default: 0] += 1
        totalSelectedElements += 1
    }

    mutating func deselect(at: Int) {
        guard var count = ayes[at] else { return }
        count -= 1
        totalSelectedElements -= 1
        ayes[at] = count == 0 ? nil : count
    }

    func selectCount(at: Int) -> Int {
        return ayes[at, default: 0]
    }

    var totalElements: Int {
        return totalSelectedElements
    }
}
```

This avoids the need for a preallocated array but still provides quick access via a dictionary and the internal count.

Comment: To me, personally, this is the best answer by *far*. You don't want to spend too much time on performance prematurely. Focus on it later, when you know there's a problem. This answer takes into account the high probability that this code will need attention in the future, isolates it, and therefore closes the client that uses it to changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to vote against storing information which can be derived from already existing data. This approach, however, may be critical to performance. So these two questions arise:

1. What is the order of magnitude in your array? Are we talking of only a few hundred items? If so, you should be able to safely ignore the added overhead.
2. How often will it be necessary to access the value in question?

Comment: 1. The array may contain elements from 100 - 5000.
2. It can vary.

Comment: So it depends on query frequency. How often would that be? You probably could offload the query by moving it into a background queue and use the delegate pattern to inform your app of any significant changes.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is what's meant by "better approach" then having a value at the ready is, of course, way quicker than going through hundreds if not thousands of elements and getting their properties and then adding them up.

If "better approach" means better API design, then the former is more versatile since from your code any object an call `select(at:)` or `deselect(at:)` and so `selectionCount` may become negative... And your code would be stateful, it would rely on the state of a variable.